# C# Roslyn API: Insert Instructions/Methods between each nodes members

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, insertion

I just got into a personal project and I would like to be able to use the Roslyn API to insert instructions / methods between class members (So methods / instructions)

I am currently able to retrieve the different child nodes like here: Namespace> Class> Fields / Methods

But I would like to know how I can insert code between fields / methods and not replace code.

(At the location of the red lines below for example)

[image: Nodes]

EDIT: After some more research I found that I can use `InsertTokensBefore`, `InsertNodesBefore` or `InsertTriviaBefore` but I don't understand how to parse my functions (actually in text/string format) to the needed parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxfactory) to build a [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.syntaxnode).

To get the syntax factory code that you need in order to create new syntax trees, have a look at the fantastic [RoslynQuoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/).
There, you can put in the C# program that you want to build via the syntax factory API:

```cs
public class RoslynClass
{
    public static int RoslynMethod(int left, int right)
    {
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

Check all options to your preference, and *Get Roslyn API calls to generate this code!*, which you can (partially) use in your production code.

Here I list an example of a *source code refactoring*, which inserts the method `public static int RoslynMethod(int left, int right)` before/after either a *field* or a *method*:

```cs
using System.Composition;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeActions;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeRefactorings;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing;

namespace RoslynTool
{
    [ExportCodeRefactoringProvider(LanguageNames.CSharp, Name = nameof(MethodInserter))]
    [Shared]
    internal sealed class MethodInserter : CodeRefactoringProvider
    {
        public override async Task ComputeRefactoringsAsync(CodeRefactoringContext context)
        {
            SyntaxNode root = await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            SyntaxNode node = root.FindNode(context.Span);

            if (node is FieldDeclarationSyntax or MethodDeclarationSyntax)
            {
                SyntaxNode newNode = CreateMethodNode();

                context.RegisterRefactoring(CodeAction.Create("Insert method before", ct => InsertBeforeAsync(context.Document, node, newNode, ct)));
                context.RegisterRefactoring(CodeAction.Create("Insert method after", ct => InsertAfterAsync(context.Document, node, newNode, ct)));
            }
        }

        private static MemberDeclarationSyntax CreateMethodNode()
        {
            return SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(
                SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(
                    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.IntKeyword)),
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier("RoslynMethod"))
                .WithModifiers(
                    SyntaxFactory.TokenList(new[] {
                        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword),
                        SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.StaticKeyword)}))
                .WithParameterList(
                    SyntaxFactory.ParameterList(
                        SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList<ParameterSyntax>(new SyntaxNodeOrToken[] {
                            SyntaxFactory.Parameter(
                                SyntaxFactory.Identifier("left"))
                            .WithType(
                                SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(
                                    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.IntKeyword))),
                            SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.CommaToken),
                            SyntaxFactory.Parameter(
                                SyntaxFactory.Identifier("right"))
                            .WithType(
                                SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(
                                    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.IntKeyword)))})))
                .WithBody(
                    SyntaxFactory.Block(
                        SyntaxFactory.SingletonList<StatementSyntax>(
                            SyntaxFactory.ReturnStatement(
                                SyntaxFactory.BinaryExpression(
                                    SyntaxKind.AddExpression,
                                    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("left"),
                                    SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("right"))))));
        }

        private static async Task<Document> InsertBeforeAsync(Document document, SyntaxNode location, SyntaxNode newNode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            DocumentEditor documentEditor = await DocumentEditor.CreateAsync(document, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            documentEditor.InsertBefore(location, newNode);

            return documentEditor.GetChangedDocument();
        }

        private static async Task<Document> InsertAfterAsync(Document document, SyntaxNode location, SyntaxNode newNode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            DocumentEditor documentEditor = await DocumentEditor.CreateAsync(document, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            documentEditor.InsertAfter(location, newNode);

            return documentEditor.GetChangedDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: insert method via roslyn source code refactorings in Visual Studio 2019]

Alternatively, the *parse* methods of the [SyntaxFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxfactory) could be used to create a new [SyntaxNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.syntaxnode), but I had some trouble getting whitespaces/trivia right in that example:

```cs
namespace RoslynTool
{
    internal sealed class MethodInserter : CodeRefactoringProvider
    {
        private static MemberDeclarationSyntax CreateMethodNode()
        {
            return SyntaxFactory.ParseMemberDeclaration(@"
        public static int RoslynMethod(int left, int right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }
");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure if that fit my requirements as all need to be done at runtime, i want to use RoselynAPI to morph an resource source to be builded at runtime to. Also as the methods to be inserted are not known in advance, i can't convert it to C# RoslynMethod. I need to put them as "text" or parsed from text. In anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: @0x0000000000000 Is the resource you want to generate your C# code from only available at runtime, or already fully accessible at compile time? Because if the resource is already known at compile time, and you are using the .NET 5.0 SDK (or later), then perhaps [Source Generators](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md) could help you out. The caveat here is that you cannot insert any new code into existing files, but instead mark your type as `partial` and then "extend" it via a Source Generator during `dotnet build`.

Comment: The flow is actually: Get Source from resources embed file (.CS), Modification at runtime (We are here), and then compile code at runtime using CSharpCode Provider. The resource is get as string, it's a common CS source. Everything is done except Modification at runtime with Roselyn. For the code inserted, WE don't know it in advance but WE get it as string too.

Comment: As actually nobody else is proposing more close solution to my problem, i will award you if nobody awnser soon.

Comment: @0x0000000000000 I'm afraid I'm not really familiar with runtime code generation. I know my way around code generation at design-time with _code fixes/refactorings_, as well as compile time generation via _source generators_, but I have very little XP with code gen at runtime. Sorry.